# JQuery Ajax server control rendering sitecore issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, sitecore, ascx

I have products which are state specifc. I am getting user's location "state" from Google geolocation (javascript). I want to pass the "state name"  to products.ascx so that they display by state. The problem I am facing is once I get the state name from Google geolocation, I am not able to send the statename without reloading the page.

1)I tried to setup [webmethod] in a su layout (aspx) and called it using jquery Ajax but I don't want to duplicate the code from products.ascx or in success of Ajax call reload the page after setting up a cookie.

2) I don't want to redirect to a new aspx page and then reload the previous page.

3)MVC is not an option in my project.

Is there anyway I can implement this functionality without reloading the page?
Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify why the webmethod was not appropriate? You've said you tried it, but I'm not sure why you gave up on it.

Comment: I tried using webmethod but I had to reload the page as the product based code is entirely in ascx file. using webmethod I've called a new aspx and on success did a location.reload which is not what I want (location.reload)

Comment: It sounds like you have issues with the structure of your solution. Can you refactor the product code to decouple it from the ascx? If you update your question to include the code that you currently have, it will make things easier.

Comment: I'm also not sure there is anything Sitecore specific about the problem

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each product has a unique id and you need to, you could setup a web api end point to give you a list of applicable productids per state (passed in via geolocation), which will be callable via an Ajax request.

Web api can be setup to work with Sitecore, these posts explain how to set this up:

http://patrickdelancy.com/2013/08/sitecore-webapi-living-harmony/

http://blog.falafel.com/sitecore-configuring-web-api/

Once you have this setup you can use JavaScript to filter your list of products on the page dynamically based on state.

Another option might be where you store the geolocation information in a cookie then have asp.net read the value of the cookie on the server side. Then you can filter the products server side based on the state.